# Grenade Blast Radius

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What are the comparative blast radii of each of the lethal and tactical grenades in MW3?

I am trying to upgrade my Recon perk and I want to know what grenades would be easiest to hit the enemy with.

Comment: I usually used flash grenades to upgrade it. Play game modes with objectives, and throw them on the target (flag, etc.), where more enemies may stand.

Comment: Recon pro is not the hardest perk to get and my experience is to just run around and play regularly. Toss a concussion or (if preferred) a flash grenade their way sometimes and you'll have recon pro in no-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tactical Grenade

- Flash Grenade - 18meters
- Concussion Grenade - 12.8m
- EMP Grenade

Lethal Grenade

- Frag - 6.5m
- Semtex - 6.5m
- Bouncing Betty - 30m
- Claymore - 6.5m
- C4 - 6.5m
- Fragmentation Grenade - 6.5m

> Campaign only and Equipment
>
> - Smoke Grenade
> - Trophy System
> - Tactical Insertion
> - Portable Radar
> - 9-Bang

[Weapons of Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Template:CoD8_Weapons)

Comment: 30m for the betty ? This seems **really** high..

Comment: And I believe you can remove smoke/trophy/tac-insert/radar/9-bang(campaign only), as they are not explosives..

Comment: And you're missing claymores with 6.5m